# Symfony2.4 SonataAdminBundle Logout error: You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-2.4

Login works fine.  Getting error at /admin/logout

> You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration.

at

`in *\vendor\sonata-project\user-bundle\Controller\AdminSecurityController.php at line 98`

I'm setting logout to true as documented:

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:      .*
            #pattern: ^/
            form-login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider:  form.csrf_provider
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

How do you avoid this error using symfony2.4, fosuserbundle1.3 and sonata-admin dev-master ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `logout` node in your security.yml should contain two subnodes defining the logout path and the target where a user gets redirected after a logout:

```
logout:
    path:   /admin/logout
    target: /
```

Not sure if this also works in sonata context, but it should work under normal conditions.

Comment: One more addition, values for path and target can also be symfony routing aliases. Thank you very much :)